# Use of custom filters in Fabric JS - getting the original back

Tags: fabricjs

I have been playing with custom filters in Fabric JS. But I just don't know how to undo anything done. Seems the pixels get overwritten by the process, which is fine, but how do I go back to the orginal? The code project starter is here:
https://github.com/pixolith/fabricjs-async-web-worker-filters

So, in the custom filter, the results are placed into the canvas as follows:

```
imageDataArray.forEach( function( data ) {
    cacheCtx.putImageData( data.data, 0, data.blocks );
} );
```

That shows the processed image in the render. But I don't understand how to "get back" the original. I have tried this before the processing:

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
var originalSource = obj._originalElement.currentSrc; // restore the original since filters trash the canvas
obj.filters[index] = filter;
obj.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

But it does not "get it back". I really don't wish to reload the image each time as they can be large at times. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Will you make a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted `obj._originalElement` is the ORIGINAL element of the image you first loaded. No reason to reload it at all, you have it there. Ready to be smashed on canvas.
So just do `obj.element = obj._originalElement` and you are back to original after a `canvas.renderAll();`